Sinusoidal Fit to Data in R
I have 45 years of daily temperature data parsed from a csv file. I was already able to convert the data in terms of years instead of days, and plotted the yearly maximum temperature, yearly minimum temperature, and yearly mean temperature as follows:
data <- read.csv(path)

L <- length(data[,1]) # Num of days
N <- length(data[,1][seq(1, L, by = 365)]) # Num of years
t <- seq(0, N-1, 1) # Years elapsed
TMAX<-as.numeric(data[seq(1,L,by=365),2]) # Yearly max temp
TMIN<-as.numeric(data[seq(1,L,by=365),3]) # Yearly min temp
TMEAN<-as.numeric(data[seq(1,L,by=365),4]) # Yearly mean temp

# Temperature plots indexed by year
par(mfrow=c(3,1), mar=c(0,0,2,0), oma=c(5,0,5,0), pin=c(4, 1), bg=NA)

plot(x = t, TMAX, col=c('red'),type='o', pch=16, xaxt="n", xlab="", main = "Temperature in Mesa, AZ (C°)", cex=1, ylim = c(min(TMIN)-5, max(TMAX)+5))
plot(x = t, TMEAN, col=c('purple'),type='o', pch=16, xaxt="n", xlab="", cex=1, ylim = c(min(TMIN)-5, max(TMAX)+5))
plot(x = t, TMIN, col=c('blue'),type='o', pch=16, cex=1, ylim = c(min(TMIN)-5, max(TMAX)+5))

mtext(side=1, line=3, "Year", font=2,cex=1)

My goal is to get a best fit of the mean temperature data using the function y = A*sin(omega * t + phi) + C, where A is the yearly amplitude, omega is the frequency, phi is the phase shift, and c is the vertical shift.
My unsuccessful attempt was:
for (i in 0:45){
  A <- (max(TMAX[i]) - min(TMIN[i]))/2
  C <- (max(TMAX[i]) + min(TMIN[i]))/2
}
t <- seq(0, N-1, 1)
omega <- 2*pi
phi <- 1/4
res1 <- nls(y ~ A*sin(omega*t + phi)+C, data = data, start=list(A=A,omega=omega,phi=0,C=C), control = list(maxiter = 5000))

Any help would be appreciated
EDIT: Running dput(data[1:10, ]), I get the following:
structure(list(daily.time = c("1/1/1980", "1/2/1980", "1/3/1980", 
"1/4/1980", "1/5/1980", "1/6/1980", "1/7/1980", "1/8/1980", "1/9/1980", 
"1/10/1980"), max.temperature = c(16.9, 17.2, 16.9, 17.5, 18.3, 
16.3, 17.4, 17.7, 13.8, 16.2), minimum.temperature = c(4.5, 1.7, 
0.9, 1.5, 0.1, 3.9, 3.3, 7.6, 6.5, 10.6), mean.temperature = c(10, 
9.2, 8.5, 9.2, 9.3, 10.1, 10.7, 12, 9.7, 13), max_diff = c(0, 
0.3, -0.3, 0.6, 0.8, -2, 1.1, 0.3, -3.9, 2.4), min_diff = c(0, 
-2.8, -0.8, 0.6, -1.4, 3.8, -0.6, 4.3, -1.1, 4.1), mean_diff = c(0, 
-0.8, -0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 0.8, 0.6, 1.3, -2.3, 3.3)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")```
and the error messages I get are:

Warning messages:
1: In max(TMAX[i]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In min(TMIN[i]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(TMAX[i]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: In min(TMIN[i]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts, scaleOffset = scOff, nDcentral = nDcntr) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf


What was unsuccessful about your attempt? Did you get warning or error messages? If so, what were they? Did something else go wrong? The plotting code, if it works, seems unrelated to this problem so I would suggest removing it from your question. But a little bit of sample data would be nice to see - dput() is the friendliest way to share sample data as it is copy/pasteable and includes all class and data structure information. Please share dput(data[1:10, ]) in your question, which will give us the first 10 rows of data.

So what exactly is your question? If you are looking for data modeling advice, you should ask at a site like [stats.se] instead where statistical questions are on-topic

I just updated my question @GregorThomas

You define N as the number of years, and t as 0, 1, ... N - 1. You don't show a definition for y, so I don't know how that's defined, but is it only yearly data you want to model? Or daily data?

@GregorThomas you're correct, sorry, y is meant to be the mean temperature data by year

If omega is known a priori (seems extremely likely that the frequency will be 1/yr!), then this is easier to do if you reformulate into a linear model of sin(2*pi*t/P) + cos(2*pi*t/P) ....

Use the plinear algorithm.  It does not require starting values for parameters that enter linearly (A, C).  With plinear the right hand side is specified as a matrix with one column per linear parameters such that each column multiplies one of the linear parameters.  Like lm the linear parameters are not specified explicitly; however, we may name each column to identify which linear parameter it is associated with.  We have also provided better starting values and defined y which was not set in the question's code.  If using different or expanded data other starting values might be needed if the data is substantially different.
dat <- data.frame(
  t = seq(0, length = nrow(data)), 
  y = data$mean.temperature
)

fo <- y ~ cbind(A = sin(omega*t + phi), C = 1)
st <- list(omega = 0.5, phi = 0.5)
fm <- nls(fo, dat, start = st, alg = "plinear")
fm

giving
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ cbind(A = sin(omega * t + phi), C = 1)
   data: parent.frame()
  omega     phi  .lin.A  .lin.C 
 0.3744  0.7023 -1.7187 10.7743 
 residual sum-of-squares: 6.063

Number of iterations to convergence: 9 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.553e-06

We plot the data (points) and the fit (solid line) and note that the 9th point (shown in solid black) seems like an outlier and if we remove it we get the dashed line fit.
plot(y ~ t, dat)
points(y ~ t, dat, subset = 9, pch = 20)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ t, dat, col = "red")

fm2 <- update(fm, subset = -9)
lines(fitted(fm2) ~ t[-9], dat, lty = 2, col = "red")


Note
Input from question.  Run this first.
data <- 
structure(list(daily.time = c("1/1/1980", "1/2/1980", "1/3/1980", 
"1/4/1980", "1/5/1980", "1/6/1980", "1/7/1980", "1/8/1980", "1/9/1980", 
"1/10/1980"), max.temperature = c(16.9, 17.2, 16.9, 17.5, 18.3, 
16.3, 17.4, 17.7, 13.8, 16.2), minimum.temperature = c(4.5, 1.7, 
0.9, 1.5, 0.1, 3.9, 3.3, 7.6, 6.5, 10.6), mean.temperature = c(10, 
9.2, 8.5, 9.2, 9.3, 10.1, 10.7, 12, 9.7, 13), max_diff = c(0, 
0.3, -0.3, 0.6, 0.8, -2, 1.1, 0.3, -3.9, 2.4), min_diff = c(0, 
-2.8, -0.8, 0.6, -1.4, 3.8, -0.6, 4.3, -1.1, 4.1), mean_diff = c(0, 
-0.8, -0.7, 0.7, 0.1, 0.8, 0.6, 1.3, -2.3, 3.3)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

